# Values not added to list in loop without constraints

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following loop:

```
deposits = Deposit.objects.all()

print('Processing '+str(len(deposits))+ ' values . .  .')


deposit_values = {}

for d in deposits:
 
    bas = Account.objects.filter(
        pk=d.account.id,
        )
    
   
    if len(bas) == 1:
        ba = bas[0]
        deposit_values[ba.id] = d.amount
    else:
        print(ba.id)
   

print(' ')
print(str(len(deposit_values))+ ' values processed.')
```

This prints the following output:

> Processing 712 values . .  .   710 values processed.

How is this possible when there are no constraints for values that go into deposit values?

Comment: @python_user as you can see from the print, the else is never hit.

Comment: Apparently there are deposits that have the same account id and you end up overwriting one with the other in your `deposit_values` dictionary.

Comment: @Selcuk wouldn't that print in the else in that instance?

Comment: No, there is still only one account but two deposits to/from the same account.

Comment: good point on that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Selcuk

there are deposits that have the same account id and you end up overwriting one with the other in your deposit_values